# java ojdbc 6 getInt() by column number returning wrong value

Tags: java, oracle11g, ojdbc

I got a pretty interesting error from ojdbc getInt() by column number.

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement("select count(*) from tableA");
rs = ps.executeQuery();
int x;
if (rs.next())
    x = rs.getInt(1);

ps = conn.prepareStatement("select count(*) as someVariable from tableA");
rs = ps.executeQuery();
int y;
if (rs.next())
    y = rs.getInt(1);
```

The value of x and y are different. y is the correct number that I am expecting.

I am using java 7 with ojdbc6.jar (11.2.0.3.0)

Thanks.

Comment: That seems unlikely. Is it the same conn (i.e. same session; or at least to same DB and credentials, with no data changes in between)? Are you initialising x and y, if so to what, and does that bear any resemblance to the value you end up with for x? Might there be code later that modifies x before you check it? An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be useful rather than a partial snippet.

Comment: x and y are initialed to 0, and both are connected to the same credential. Both are run separately.

Answer (score 0):

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement("select count(*) as someVariable from tableA");
ps = conn.prepareStatement("select count(*) as result from tableA");
rs = ps.executeQuery();
int x;
if (rs.next())
    x = rs.getInt("result");

ps = conn.prepareStatement("select count(*) as someVariable from tableA");
rs = ps.executeQuery();
int y;
if (rs.next())
    y = rs.getInt("someVariable");
```

Didn't you forget about rs.close(), conn.close(), statement.close()? It is better to youse try-with resources, than just try.

```
try(Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("DBpath","usr","pswd")) {
    //doSomething
}
```

In that case you don't need to close them, they close automatically. 
Note: You can do it only with closeable objects.